# JQuery Mobile Navbar Background Color

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navbar, jquery-mobile-navbar

Hi all I am currently using JQuery Mobile to create a web app. I currently have a navbar across the top of my page with a series of images centered inside each button on the navbar. I have set the "data-theme=b" but this doesnt give me the colour I want. I have tried removing this and setting the background colour using the css but I havent had much luck.

I was just wondering is it possible to change the navbar colour using just the css or some jquery.

My code for the navbar is:

```
<div data-role="navbar"><!-- navbar -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" data-transition="flip" ><img src="../../images/icons/SearchLarge.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"></a></li>
    <li><a href="../../index.html" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b"><img src="../../images/icons/ApplicationL.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"></a></li>
    <li><a href="../app/index.html" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b"><img src="../../images/icons/App3.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b"><img src="../../images/icons/View.png" height="30px;" width="10px;"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b"><img src="../../images/icons/Last2.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"></a></li>
   </ul>
 </div><!-- /navbar -->
```

Comment: I want to know if it's possible to customize the navbar background color through ThemeRoller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code.

**`Navbar`** color theme is blue by default and **`data-theme="b"`** is that blue color. Change it to a to see the difference.

Working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vTBGa/

```
<div data-role="navbar"><!-- navbar -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" data-transition="flip" ><img src="../../images/icons/SearchLarge.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="../../index.html" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b"><img src="../../images/icons/ApplicationL.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="../app/index.html" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b"><img src="../../images/icons/App3.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b"><img src="../../images/icons/View.png" height="30px;" width="10px;"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-ajax="false" data-theme="a"><img src="../../images/icons/Last2.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"/></a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

If you are manually changing background color it must be done with a **`!important`** override because in any other case your custom **`CSS`** will be discarded.

```
#other-color {
    background: red !important;
}
```

In case you want to find more about how jQuery Mobile handles markup enhancements, then take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, it is my personal blog. There can be bound much much more then this, also this topic is discussed in the chapter:

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the navbar with a div with classes `ui-body` and `ui-body-b`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mR6Ut/)**

```
<div class="ui-body-b ui-body">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="star">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="arrow-r">E</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" data-transition="flip" ><img src="../../images/icons/SearchLarge.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"></a></li>

                <li style="background=#000;"><a href="../../index.html" data-ajax="false"><img src="../../images/icons/ApplicationL.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"></a></li>

                <li syle="background=#000;"><a href="../app/index.html" data-ajax="false"><img src="../../images/icons/App3.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"></a></li>

                <li><a href="#" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b"><img src="../../images/icons/View.png" height="30px;" width="10px;"></a></li>

                <li><a href="#" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b"><img src="../../images/icons/Last2.png" height="30px;" width="30px;"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```